# running a script to read three values then output the first value to a txt file if the 2nd and 3rd add up to equal above a set number

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I have a file with values within it that I need to sift through for specific reference numbers that are over a certain value. The trouble is that this file is also full of a lot of junk info that I don't need.

The file looks something like this:

```
file 657657/78687686
blah blah blah
blah 
blah 5 blah 8 value1 456456 value2 678678 blah 7
blah 2 blah 5 value1 9878787 value2 4544454 blah 2
blah 1 blah 8 value1 4584 value2 21231232 blah 5

blah blah
blah

file 657657/78687686
blah blah blah
blah 
blah 5 blah 0 value1 871245 value2 555558 blah 7
blah 6 blah 7 value1 6666 value2 777877 blah 1
```

I want to feed that into a script and have it add the values and work out if the total value is above say 500000. If it is then it sends the file number to a seperate txt file and then moves on to the next file number and so on.

I have no idea where to start with this, any help would be appreciated.

This is being run on an AIX box and in a .ksh

Comment: clarification: I'm looking to add the numbers from value1 together and see if it exceeds 50000. Then move to the next file number.

Comment: Is your example data from a single file, or 2 files? and the only values of interest are the numbers immediately after the `value1` field?  your example has 2 entries for `file` but the same value (657657/78687686) does each occurrence of `file` reset the counter, or would you need to sum all of the `value1` entries across all `files` of the same value (ie, 5x numbers in this case)

Comment: the values are from a single file, however the file has multiple file numbers. I want to add up the numbers immediately after each value1 but they should only apply the file number immediately above that block.

Comment: this code wants to run on a loop through out the file.

Comment: please provide a 3rd block of data that won't get printed (ie, total < 500000), then add a section showing the expected totals and the desired/final output; see [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @OP: Basically, you should do some shell-programming. Start with this: `CurrentFile='nameless'; Sum=0; State=0; while read Word; do case "$Word" in file) ... ;; value1) ... ;; *) ... ;; esac; done <input.file`